# A variant of Hilbert's inequality

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, trigonometric-series

Let $(z_r)$ be a sequence of complex numbers and let $(\alpha_r)$ be real numbers with the property that $\|\alpha_r - \alpha_s\| \geq \delta > 0$ if $r \neq s$, where for $k \in \mathbb{R}$, $\|k\|$ denotes the distance from $k$ to the nearest integer.

Montgomery and Vaughan proved (see for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_inequality) that 
$$
\left|\sum_{\substack{r,s \\ r \neq s}} \dfrac{z_r\overline{z_s}}{\sin \pi (\alpha_r - \alpha_s)}\right| \leq \delta^{-1} \sum_{r}|z_r|^2.
$$

**Question:** Supposing we replace the $z_r\overline{z_s}$ above with a more general $f(s,r)\overline{f(r,s)}$ with $f : \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C}$, can we prove (or is it known) or disprove that
$$
\left|\sum_{\substack{r,s \\ r \neq s}} \dfrac{f(s,r)\overline{f(r,s)}}{\sin \pi (\alpha_r - \alpha_s)}\right| \leq \delta^{-1} \sum_{r}|f(r,r)|^2.
$$
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry what prevent $f$ from being zero on the diagonal, i.e. $f(r,r) = 0$?

Comment: Hilbert's inequality works for any sequence of complex numbers, so it seems to me quite general. Why do you need to prove it with $f(s,r)$?

Comment: @John M. Thanks for noticing that. Yes there may be some issues with that..

Comment: @Marco: there may be functions $f(s,r)$ which can't be written as $z(s)z(r)$